# Tile Container SAPUI5 event press get id

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I already create tiles container and want to conditional routing to other page. if I click tiles1, I route to home, click tiles2, I route to page2. I want route by id click. How to I code in controller?

I already code but failed:

alert(oControlEvent.getParamaters("items"));

xml view:

```
                    <m:Panel>
                        <m:content>
                            <l:HorizontalLayout
                                id="TileContainerExpanded"
                                allowWrapping="true"
                                content="{/kepesertaan}">
                                    <m:GenericTile class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop tileLayout" 
                                        header="{header}" subheader="{subheader}" press="pressKepesertaan">
                                        <m:tileContent>
                                            <m:TileContent>
                                                <m:content>
                                                    <m:ImageContent description="{id}" src="{icon}"/>
                                                </m:content>
                                            </m:TileContent>
                                        </m:tileContent>
                                    </m:GenericTile>
                            </l:HorizontalLayout>
                        </m:content>
                    </m:Panel>
```

How to solved this problem? Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how I would solve it (assuming I understood correctly your question):

```js
pressKepesertaan: function(oEvent){
    var sPath = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath();
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
    var oContext = oModel.getProperty(sPath);
    this.getRouter().navTo(oContext.id); //navigate to route
}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/ruvodekare/4/edit?html,output) is an example.